# sec:authorize always returning same view in browser for both isAuthenticated() and isAnonymous() in thymeleaf view

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

> home Controller

```
package com.book.controller;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import com.book.entity.User;
import com.book.security.entity.PasswordResetToken;
import com.book.security.entity.Role;
import com.book.security.entity.UserRole;
import com.book.security.impl.MailConstructor;
import com.book.security.impl.SecurityUtility;
import com.book.security.impl.UserSecurityService;
import com.book.security.repo.UserService;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    @Autowired
    private MailConstructor mailConstructor;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private UserSecurityService userSecurityService;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("classActiveLogin", true);
        return "myAccount";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/forgetPassword")
    public String forgetPassword(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute("email") String email, Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("classActiveForgetPassword", true);

        User user = userService.findByEmail(email);

        if (user == null) {
            model.addAttribute("emailNotExist", true);
            return "myAccount";
        }

        String password = SecurityUtility.randomPassword();

        String encryptedPassword = SecurityUtility.passwordEncoder().encode(password);
        user.setPassword(encryptedPassword);

        userService.save(user);

        String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        userService.createPasswordResetTokenForUser(user, token);

        String appUrl = "http://" + request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort() + request.getContextPath();

        SimpleMailMessage emails = mailConstructor.constructResetTokenEmail(appUrl, request.getLocale(), token, user,
                password);

        mailSender.send(emails);

        model.addAttribute("emailSent", "true");

        return "myAccount";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/newUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String newUserPost(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute("email") String userEmail,
            @ModelAttribute("username") String username, Model model) throws Exception {
        model.addAttribute("classActiveNewAccount", true);
        model.addAttribute("email", userEmail);
        model.addAttribute("username", username);

        if (userService.findByUsername(username) != null) {
            model.addAttribute("usernameExists", true);

            return "myAccount";
        }

        if (userService.findByEmail(userEmail) != null) {
            model.addAttribute("emailExists", true);

            return "myAccount";
        }

        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername(username);
        user.setEmail(userEmail);

        String password = SecurityUtility.randomPassword();

        String encryptedPassword = SecurityUtility.passwordEncoder().encode(password);
        user.setPassword(encryptedPassword);

        Role role = new Role();
        role.setRoleId(1);
        role.setName("ROLE_USER");
        Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();
        userRoles.add(new UserRole(user, role));
        userService.createUser(user, userRoles);

        String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        userService.createPasswordResetTokenForUser(user, token);

        String appUrl = "http://" + request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort() + request.getContextPath();

        SimpleMailMessage email = mailConstructor.constructResetTokenEmail(appUrl, request.getLocale(), token, user,
                password);

        mailSender.send(email);

        model.addAttribute("emailSent", "true");

        return "myAccount";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/newUser")
    public String newUser(Locale locale, @RequestParam("token") String token, Model model) {
        PasswordResetToken passToken = userService.getPasswordResetToken(token);

        if (passToken == null) {
            String message = "Invalid Token.";
            model.addAttribute("message", message);
            return "redirect:/badRequest";
        } else {

            User user = passToken.getUser();
            String username = user.getUsername();

            UserDetails userDetails = userSecurityService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,
                    userDetails.getPassword(), userDetails.getAuthorities());

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

            model.addAttribute("user", user);

            model.addAttribute("classActiveEdit", true);
            return "myProfile";
        }
    }
}
```

> Header.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">
<head th:fragment="common-header">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

<title>Le's Bookstore</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="/css/non-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link rel="icon" href="/image/applie-touch-icon.png" />
</head>

<body>
    <div th:fragment="navbar">
        <div class="page-top"
            style="width: 100%; height: 20px; background-color: #f46b42;"></div>
        <!-- Static navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LE'S BOOKSTORE</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
                            data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                            aria-expanded="false">BOOKS <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Browse the bookshelf</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Store hours &#38; Directions</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>

                            </ul></li>
                        <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="keyword" class="form-control"
                                    placeholder="Book title" />
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
                        </form>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">SHOPPING CART</a></li>
                        <li sec:authorize="isAnonymous()"><a th:href="@{/login}">MY ACCOUNT</a></li>
                        <li sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"><a th:href="@{/myProfile}">MY ACCOUNT</a></li>
                        <li sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"><a th:href="@{/logout}">LOGOUT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!--/.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div th:fragment="body-bottom-scripts">
        <script
            src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

> SecurityConfig

```
package com.book.security.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import com.book.security.impl.SecurityUtility;
import com.book.security.impl.UserSecurityService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserSecurityService userSecurityService;

    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return SecurityUtility.passwordEncoder();
    }

    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = {
            "/css/**",
            "/js/**",
            "/image/**",
            "/",
            "/newUser",
            "/forgetPassword",
            "/login",
            "/fonts/**"
    };

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable().cors().disable()
            .formLogin().failureUrl("/login?error")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout").deleteCookies("remember-me").permitAll()
            .and()
            .rememberMe();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userSecurityService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

}
```

> pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.rakib.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>book-shop</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>book-shop</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr-complete</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

> Problem:
>   sec:authorize returning true for both isAuthenticated() and isAnonymous() in thymeleaf view. i try to hide my_Profile, Log in when user log in and when log out then show only Log in.
>   BUT ITS not working ....
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzArl.png)

not working in both condition. please help me sir to continue the project.

SHOPPING CART

MY ACCOUNT
                        MY ACCOUNT
                        LOGOUT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

When you upgrade your security version 5 and it will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this

```
<li sec:authorize="isAnonymous()"><a th:href="@{/login}">MY ACCOUNT</a></li>
```

For this

```
<li sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()"><a th:href="@{/login}">MY ACCOUNT</a></li>
```